# OOP to stimulate Book and Bookstore class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

Im trying to simulate a bookstore using python with using a book class and a bookstore class. How do i relate the 2 classes and how do I make so that the book class will be automatically added to the BookStore class thats used to manipulate the Books

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, ID, title, ISBN, authorsList, edition,
                publication_date, no_of_pages, purchase_price,
                selling_price, quantity, discount):
        try:
            self.ID = int(ID)
            self.title = str(title)
            self.ISBN = str(ISBN)
            self.authorsList = str(authorsList)
            self.edition = str(edition)
            self.publication_date = str(publication_date)
            self.no_of_pages = int(no_of_pages)
            self.purchase_price = float(purchase_price)
            self.selling_price = float(selling_price)
            self.quantity = int(quantity)
            self.discount = float(discount)
        except:
            print("Error has occurred!")

    def getID(self):
        try:
            return self.ID
        except:
           print("Error has occurred!")

    def setID(self, ID):
        try:
            self.ID = ID
        except:
            print("Error has occurred!")

    def gettitle(self):
        try:
            return self.title
        except:
            print("Error has occurred!")



    def __str__(self):
        return "Book ID: {}\n Book Title: {}\n Book ISBN: {}\n Book Authors List: {}\n Book Edition: {}\n Book Publication Date: {}\n Book Number of pages: {}\n Book Purchase Price: {}\n Book Selling Price: {}\n Book Quantity: {}\n Book Discount: {}".format(self.ID, self.title, self.ISBN, self.authorsList, self.edition, self.publication_date, self.no_of_pages, self.purchase_price, self.selling_price, self.quantity, self.discount)


class BookStore(Book):

    def __init__(self):
        self.itemlist =[]

    def addBook(self, Book):
        return self.itemlist.append(Book)

    def DisplayBook():
        for i in self.itemlist:
            print(i.__str__())


    def SearchBookID():
        self.itemlist = []
        for Book in self.ID:
            if Book.ID == ID:
                ID.append(Book)
        return ID

    def delBookID():
        return self.itemlist.remove(Book)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to -- although it's not the recommended way -- you can create something like a `class variable`

```py
>>> class BookStore:
        booklist = []

>>> BookStore.booklist.append(1)
>>> BookStore.booklist.append(2)
>>> BookStore.booklist
[1, 2]
```

now in `__init__` method in your `Book` class to add `BookStore.booklist.append(book)`